# What is a word for someone who hates or fears nature?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, pejorative-language, phobias

I know that *misanthrope* is someone who hates other humans or humankind in general.  I am interested to know if there is a word for one who hates nature herself.

Comment: I'm not sure a word exists, but **agoraphobia** is a fear of wide open spaces and sufferers tend to stay indoors.

Comment: **Anti-ecologist** or **anti-environmental person** are definitions that potentially are close to your definition of people who hate nature.

Comment: If you ask some nature-lovers, they might quickly respond: **industrialist**

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Comment: I have this same issue and haven't found an answer either. I think it is linked to mental health somehow, but nature is cruel and that's basically it. Everyone seems to think it's some sort of benevolent force but all I can see is that almost every animal in the wild dies a horrific death simply to feed the next thing. I see that as cruelty. Also, we as humans argue that to be indifferent is to be evil. I happen to agree with this analogy, but the problem is that reinforces my view of nature itself. It has been argued to me as a point of good that nature is not good or evil, but indifferent. I

Comment: Not the answer, but a good explanation of the point of view: “I hate nature. I really do. Nature is composed entirely of sticks, dirt, fall-down places, biting and stinging things, and savageries too numerous to list. And I'm not the only one who feels this way. Man has been building cities since the year oughty-ought, just to get away from this stuff.” [Sue Grafton](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/288767-i-hate-nature-i-really-do-nature-is-composed-entirely)

Answer (score 5):

**[biophobia](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/topic/1714435/biophilia-hypothesis#ref1090174)** is the fear of nature which covers aversion to and discomfort in natural places. It also covers different types of [specific phobias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_phobia) which are natural environmental type. For example: [Hylophobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hylophobia) (fear of wood, forest and trees) and [agrizoophobia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrizoophobia) (fear of wild animals)

> Some of the most powerful evidence for an innate connection between humans and nature comes from studies of **biophobia (the fear of nature)**, in which measurable physiological responses are produced upon exposure to an object that is the source of fear, such as a snake or a spider. These responses are the result of evolution in a world in which humans were constantly vulnerable to predators, poisonous plants and animals, and natural phenomena such as thunder and lightning.
>
> Fear was a fundamental connection with nature that enabled survival, and, as a result, humans needed to maintain a close relationship with their environment, using sights and sounds as vital cues, particularly for fight-or-flight responses.

---

Further explanation from the book "Transformative Eco-education for Human and Planetary Survival" *edited by Jing Lin, Rebecca L. Oxford*:

[image]

Comment: That article is dodgy, Dependence on technology does not imply, ipso facto, eco- and bio-phobia. At first, it just replicates the actual dependancy.

Answer (score 2):

By analogy with [**nature lover**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nature-lover), consider the term [**nature hater**](http://www.ecospherics.net/pages/RoweEisenRev.html).

> "*Yet, among these self-righteous poisoners of the earth, seas, and skies and killers of species, there exists a particular breed of [**nature haters**](http://books.google.fr/books?id=GdD2RJjw-ocC&pg=PA50&dq=%22nature+haters%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=xr5iU67aA6aa1AX2o4GIBA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22nature%20haters%22&f=false), the spawn of Francis Bacon, a man who loved mankind above all else...*"